How do Protestants define what constitutes getting married?
Background
The Hebrew bible and New Testament make numerous references to the concept of marriage (Exodus 21:10; Genesis 2:24) and even include stories involving weddings such as the famous Wedding at Cana. The NT also includes numerous commands for married couples such as Ephesians 5:22-33.
However neither the Hebrew bible nor NT define what is involved in getting married, or what constitutes a wedding. In contrast, Jewish laws of kiddushin describe three ways a marriage can occur: sexual intercourse, a legal document, or the exchange of money.
Question
How have Protestants as Sola Scriptura proponents defined the boundaries of acceptable weddings without a corresponding biblical definition? Do they rely wholly on the state? How do they define when a couple is religiously considered married?

Does Sola Scriptura mean that the Bible defines everything that's needed in all aspects of our lives? Why is this question singling out how to marry, as opposed to which side of the road we should drive on?

@RayButterworth Why is this question singling out how to marry - the New Testament includes commands specifically for married couples, and is silent about traffic rules. So the obvious question is what makes a couple married?

Sola Scriptura would say that the Bible doesn't define it. "Acceptable" weddings is not therefore a doctrinal concept. So most Christians say that it depends on what is common in the particular culture, excepting things like visiting other religions' temples.

So most Christians say that it depends on what is common in the particular culture, excepting things like visiting other religions' temples sources would be nice, especially any describing the practices and beliefs of Sola Scriptura christians

@AviAvraham says "the obvious question is what makes a couple married?".  I suspect the answer will boil down to "I don't know what […] is, but I know it when I see it".


How do Sola Scriptura adherents define what constitutes getting married?

As a non-Sola Scriptura denomination, the Roman Catholic Church considers the marriage ceremony to be a sacrament, well defined and administered only by priests, and only under specific circumstances.
On the other hand, Sola Scriptura denominations stress the importance of the marriage itself (and family), and not the ceremony.
When asked for a test for obscenity in 1964, Supreme Court Justice Potter Stewart replied: "I know it when I see it.".
Marriage is very similar. If people live according to the biblical requirements of marriage, then they are de facto married, regardless of what formal ceremonies, if any, were performed.
British Common Law, which is the basis for law in most English-speaking countries, in fact defines marriage that way:
if a man and a woman live together as if they were married, after a certain prescribed length of time they are considered married.
A wedding ceremony may be socially important to the families of the couple, but as far as many churches are concerned, there is nothing doctrinal about it.
Consider how important marriage is in this following example.
The Southern Baptist Convention's Marriage and the family in the Baptist tradition - ERLC
provides a long history of what marriage has meant through the ages:

In 1580, the Waterlander Mennonites issued “A Brief Confession of the Principal Articles of the Christian Faith,” and said:

Article XXXIX. OF MARRIAGE
Marriage we profess to be an ordinance of God which must be entered into according to the primal institution (a);
that each man have his own only wife (b) and each woman her own and one husband.
This marriage cannot be dissolved except for the cause of adultery (c).
Neither do we think it allowable that any of us should enter into marriage outside the Church of God, with wicked, unbelieving or carnal men (d),
and we condemn that (as other sins) by the word of God, the state of the time and the reason of things.
Gen. 2:22; Matt. 19:4.
I Cor. 7:2; Eph. 5:31.
Matt. 19:9.
Deut. 7:3; I Cor. 7:39.

1677
…

XLVII. Article Of Marriage
Marriage is to be between one Man, and one Woman; neither is it lawful for any Man, to have more than one wife, nor for any woman to have more than one husband, at the same time.
And it is lawful for all sorts of people to marry, who are able of judgment to give their consent.
But marriage must not be within the degree of consanguinity, or affinity, forbidden in the word, nor can any such incestuous marriages ever be made lawful by any law of man, or consent of parties, to live together as man and wife.
And it is the duty of christians [sic] to marry in them Lord, and therefore those that profess the true religion, ought not to marry with infidels, or idolaters, nor prophane [sic] wicked persons in their life, nor yet with any that maintain damnable heresies.
…

Thus, with the 17th century we see the Baptist perspective on marriage and family still rooted in the Reformation tradition of Sola Scriptura and now expanding more specifically into the realm of family life and also warning of aberrations that are divergent from the biblical design. The Bible informs and directs the definition of marriage still in the 17th century.
…
the 1958 Southern Baptist Encyclopedia entry for “Marriage and the Family” affirmed the positions established during the previous centuries by Baptist forebears. In part the entry states,

In marriage is found God’s provision for the basic needs of man and for the propagation of the human race.
The home should be the nearest approximation of heaven possible on earth.
The intent of God is that each member shall voluntarily accept certain duties and responsibilities in the family relationship. The husband is to love his wife with an unselfish, sacrificial love … He is to serve voluntarily as head of the family.
Likewise, the wife is to love her husband and hold him in such respect that she voluntarily subjects herself to him … It is not the duty of the husband to bring the wife under subjugation.
Parents are to love their children and … are to rear their children in such a way as to provide instruction, training, discipline, and counsel.
The marriage relationship should never be established until both man and woman understand the intent of God for marriage and home relations and are willing to accept the responsibilities peculiar to their place in the family relationship. The nearer marriages and homes approximate the intent of God, the more blessed they will be, and the more blessed will be all relationships in human community.

The statement, adopted in 1998 and now included in The Baptist Faith and Message 2000 is as follows:

XVIII. The Family
God has ordained the family as the foundational institution of human society.
It is composed of persons related to one another by marriage, blood, or adoption.
Marriage is the uniting of one man and one woman in covenant commitment for a lifetime.
It is God’s unique gift to reveal the union between Christ and His church and to provide for the man and the woman in marriage the framework for intimate companionship, the channel of sexual expression according to biblical standards, and the means for procreation of the human race.
The husband and wife are of equal worth before God, since both are created in God’s image.
The marriage relationship models the way God relates to His people.
A husband is to love his wife as Christ loved the church.
He has the God-given responsibility to provide for, to protect, and to lead his family.
A wife is to submit herself graciously to the servant leadership of her husband even as the church willingly submits to the headship of Christ.
She, being in the image of God as is her husband and thus equal to him, has the God-given responsibility to respect her husband and to serve as his helper in managing the household and nurturing the next generation.
Children, from the moment of conception, are a blessing and heritage from the Lord.
Parents are to demonstrate to their children God’s pattern for marriage. Parents are to teach their children spiritual and moral values and to lead them, through consistent lifestyle example and loving discipline, to make choices based on biblical truth. Children are to honor and obey their parents.


Their definition of marriage has grown over the centuries to stress the importance of family, but its basic ideas have remained the same, following the biblical directives regarding marriage.
As for the wedding ceremony itself ("getting married"), it may be a wonderful event, but it is hardly relevant when it comes to salvation and God's will.

Marriage in the RCC is administered by the spouses, with a priest or a deacon leading the ceremony and as a witness for the church.

Orthodox church also views it as a sacrament. But I note you did answer from the protestant perspective. It is so odd to think of marriage as something unrelated to salvation or God's will.

@Wyrsa It is more fundamental than salvation since the first marriage was prior to the Fall.  Consider how Satan never touched Job's wife even though God never strictly forbade it.  God said not to touch the man or his life.  In the heavenly realms, one flesh means one flesh.

@ABMK Lay persons can administer sacraments to one another?

Yes, but only baptism and marriage.

@llrs  uh... how strange it must be for your churches. Orthodox church has a layman can perform a baptism, in an emergency if the priest cannot arrive in time. Marriage? No.

Calling something different "strange" is maybe not the most friendly way. Maybe it is also different that in the RCC the deacon can take the role of the priest in baptism and marriage? There are more differences between our churches. One would almost think there is a reason they have split.

Both Adam and Jesus of Nazareth stated the definition of marriage.

Therefore shall a man leave his father and his mother, and shall cleave unto his wife: and they shall be one flesh. [Genesis 2:24 KJV]


For this cause shall a man leave father and mother, and shall cleave to his wife: and they twain shall be one flesh. [Matthew 19:5]

He is then forbidden to depart from her or to thrust her away. (Saving for one reason, the dissolution of the marriage by unfaithfulness.)
I don't see anything difficult about this definition.
And this is what is generally accepted among Protestant Christians as far as I can tell.

How this is implemented in practice ; by ceremony, by documentation and by publication ; differs from region to region. Which is a matter of mere practicalities and local customs and family preferences.
Ultimately, the concept is clear and precise.
Marriage (and this is not merely Protestant but generally so everywhere) is a public matter, socially. It is neither secret nor merely a family occasion.
It is public and it is publicised.
Civilised societies (and Protestantism is a civilised part of society, else it is not, genuinely, 'Protestant') are structured around marriage and families.
This is both social and public.
Thus, most Protestant marriages are commenced with a public ceremony involving members of the local congregation.

The Westminster Confession of Faith is considered by a number of the Protestant denominations to be 'the subordinate standard of faith' (the scriptures being the primary standard) and of marriage it states :

CHAPTER XXIV. OF MARRIAGE, AND DIVORCE
I. Marriage is to be between one man and one woman: neither is it lawful for any man to have more than one wife, nor for any woman to have more than one husband, at the same time, (Gen 2:24; Mat 19:5-6; Pro 2:17).
II. Marriage was ordained for the mutual help of husband and wife, (Gen 2:18); for the increase of mankind with a legitimate issue, and of the Church with an holy seed, (Mal 2:15); and for preventing of uncleanness, (1Co 7:2, 9).
III. It is lawful for all sorts of people to marry, who are able with judgment to give their consent, (Hbr 13:4; 1Ti 4:3; 1Co 7:36-38; Gen 24:57-58). Yet is it the duty of Christians to marry only in the Lord, (1Co 7:39). And therefore such as profess the true reformed religion should not marry with infidels, papists, or other idolaters: neither should such as are godly be unequally yoked, by marrying with such as are notoriously wicked in their life, or maintain damnable heresies, (Gen 34:14; Exd 34:16; Deu 7:3-4; 1Ki 11:4; Neh 13:25-27; Mal 2:11-12; 2Co 6:14).
IV. Marriage ought not to be within the degrees of consanguinity or affinity forbidden by the Word, (Lev 18; 1Co 5:1; Amo 2:7). Nor can such incestuous marriages ever be made lawful by any law of man or consent of parties, so as those persons may live together as man and wife, (Mar 6:18; Lev 18:24-28). The man may not marry any of his wife’s kindred, nearer in blood than he may of his own: nor the woman of her husband’s kindred, nearer in blood than of her own, (Lev 20:19-21).
V. Adultery or fornication committed after a contract, being detected before marriage, giveth just occasion to the innocent party to dissolve that contract, (Mat 1:18-20). In the case of adultery after marriage, it is lawful for the innocent party to sue out a divorce, (Mat 5:31-32): and, after the divorce, to marry another, as if the offending party were dead, (Mat 19:9; Rom 7:2-3).
VI. Although the corruption of man be such as is apt to study arguments unduly to put asunder those whom God hath joined together in marriage: yet, nothing but adultery, or such wilful desertion as can no way be remedied by the Church, or civil magistrate, is cause sufficient of dissolving the bond of marriage, (Mat 19:8-9; 1Co 7:15; Mat 19:6): wherein, a public and orderly course of proceeding is to be observed; and the persons concerned in it not left to their own wills, and discretion, in their own case, (Deu 24:1-4).

Of Marriage and Divorce, The Westminster Confession of Faith
It is noticeable that the Confession makes no attempt to legislate or even to advise as to the practicalities of ceremony.
Which is to be expected in a movement which rejects ritual and embraces the word of God, which, itself, does not make any ruling on the matter.

I wonder why someone down-voted this, without comment, when there's nothing obviously wrong with it? +1 to even it out.

@RayButterworth IDK, probably the same downvoter who has downvoted my question despite nothing wrong with it
